# Android Virtual Device -HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode - qemu: could not load initial ram disk ''

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, ram, qemu

I installed the Intel HAX for the AVD, everything's OK.

I created a AVD with this characteristics

```
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'Galaxy' based on Android 4.1.2, Intel Atom (x86) processor,
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=no
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Google
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=320
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=1197498893
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=Galaxy Nexus
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.back=none
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=yes
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=64
[2014-01-15 21:47:41 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512
```

So, when i have to start it, says

```
[2014-01-15 21:40:46 - LaMega] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Galaxy'
[2014-01-15 21:41:02 - Emulator] emulator: device fd:580
[2014-01-15 21:41:02 - Emulator] 
[2014-01-15 21:41:02 - Emulator] HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
[2014-01-15 21:41:03 - Emulator] qemu: could not load initial ram disk ''
```

i try to create a new one, with more ram, with less ram, with another version of the SDK, but nothing.

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 with a Intel Core i5 2430M and 8GB of ram memory

Did Anyone have this problem?

Thank u very much!

Comment: You'll probably need to reboot your laptop into BIOS (Press F3 or F11 when rebooting, I forget) and explicitly enable "virtual emulation" (or something similar sounding which should be under the security tab of your BIOS settings).

Comment: It's enabled already...

Comment: Do you have VirtualBox running? I had the same error, when I tried another approach of Android Emulator using VirtualBox. I simply closed the instance of VirtualBox and I was able to run my project on a built in already defined Virtual Device.

Comment: @BoldizsárZsolt thanks for a tip about VB. Helped me.