# AVD not getting started in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run a simple project in Android Studio. But the AVD is not getting started. It shows just:

```html
emulator: device fd:544
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
```

According to this there is only problem with audio input (that might not a big problem).
But after waiting for long AVD stays as blank screen, no home screen loaded.
For your info:

- I have virtualization enabled
- No virtual box running on my machine
- Android studio 1.0.1
- AVD is default Nexus 5 with API 21
  Please some help.

Comment: Guys don't close or downvote as duplicate to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152314/android-virtual-device-hax-is-working-and-emulator-runs-in-fast-virt-mode-qem) i tried the provided solution as i mentioned that there is no virtual box in my machine, but still no help

Comment: Created a new AVD Nexus S, from default list given...it is working fine. I don't know why there is problem loading Nexus 5, even memory allocated is same (If that might be a cause).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793956/android-emulator-wont-run-application-started-from-eclipse

Comment: And where do i see the log of whatever is happening on my avd (if i close the app or some button is pressed), as in eclipse it is shown in logcat